# "[WinError 6] The handle is invalid" with Urllib

Tags: python, urllib

```
import urllib.request

def Download(url, file_name):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)

f = open("links.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    for x in range (1, 5):
        filenaame = x


        cut_string = line.split('?$')
        new_string = cut_string[0]
        numerator = new_string.split('/1/')
        separator = ''

        link = (separator.join(numerator[0] + "/{}/".format(x) + numerator[1]))

        file_name = link.split('/{}/'.format(x))
        file_name = file_name[1]
        file_name = file_name.split('.')
        file_name = (separator.join(file_name[0] + "{}".format(filenaame)))
        filenaame =+ 1

        print("Downloading: {}".format(file_name))
        Download(link, filenaame)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\downloader\rr.py", line 29, in <module>
    Download(link, filenaame)
  File "C:\python\downloader\rr.py", line 5, in Download
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 258, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I have googled a lot about this and in every result I found the person was using the subprocess module, which I'm not, which makes it even more difficult.

The code is for downloading images. It does download the first one successfully, then it crashes. Anyone know what's causing the error? I'm still a beginner.

Comment: `filenaame` is an integer. You probably want to call `Download(link, file_name)` (there's a reason why you should name your variables properly)

Answer (score 0):

you're passing your *counter* as a second parameter. In the end the function uses that as a *filename* to copy the downloaded data to.

By passing an integer you enable the "pass a lowlevel file descriptor" to [`open`](http://file%20is%20either%20a%20string%20or%20bytes%20object%20giving%20the%20pathname%20(absolute%20or%20relative%20to%20the%20current%20working%20directory)%20of%20the%20file%20to%20be%20opened%20or%20an%20integer%20file%20descriptor%20of%20the%20file%20to%20be%20wrapped.):

> file is either a string or bytes object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or **an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped**.

But the file descriptor doesn't exist (fortunately!)

Let's reproduce the issue here:

```
>>> open(4,"rb")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

the fix is obviously:

```
Download(link, file_name)
```

(I'd suggest that you rename your `filenaame` counter for something more meaningful, it avoids mistakes like that)

Answer (score 0):

At this line,

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

here **file_name** should be a string so before calling **Download(link, filenaame)** make integer filenaame to string try.

```
Download(link, str(filenaame))
```

Sample working for downloading an image

```
def download_img(url):
    name = random.randrange(100,1000)
    full_name = str(name)+ ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)


download_img("http://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/25d/eagle-1523807.jpg")
```